# jOOQ - Get constraint violation

Tags: java, jooq

I have a method call that may throw a constraint violation exception and if so I would like to perform a specific flow.

So far what I'm doing is the following:

```
try {
    accountService.save(account);
} catch (DataAccessException ex) {
    if(SQLStateClass.C23_INTEGRITY_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION == ex.sqlStateClass()
       && ex.getCause() instanceof PSQLException psqlException
       && psqlException.getServerErrorMessage().getConstraint().contains( "account_name" ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid that horrendous if?

Answer (score 1):

There are pending feature requests like this one:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13299

The problem is that this area is poorly specified both by the SQL standard and JDBC, and even worse implemented by RDBMS and drivers. While it would obviously be very nice to *programmatically know* what objects had caused a particular exception, a lot of these error messages aren't designed for processing by a machine, but rather by a human - so, parsing the text is the way to go here.

Of course, you don't have to repeat yourself. You can write a utility that takes care of your logic, e.g. (just one option):

```java
void checkConstraintViolation(
    Runnable runnable,
    Consumer<String> perTableHandling
) {
    try {
        runnable.run();
    }
    catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        if(SQLStateClass.C23_INTEGRITY_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION == ex.sqlStateClass()
             && ex.getCause() instanceof PSQLException psqlException)
            perTableHandling.accept(psqlException.getServerErrorMessage().getConstraint());
        else
            throw ex;
    }
}
```